# Can OpenVPN run and connect on startup?

Tags: windows-7, openvpn, automation, startup

I just set up an OpenVPN Server on an Amazon EC2 Instance. Now I want the client (me in this case) to connect to the server when my computer boots.

I have read that it can be done by modifying a registry entry, but all the things I found apparently do not apply to Win7 (Which I am currently running), so all of the registry entries they mention are not in my registry.

Maybe some command line entries on startup to launch the GUI and connect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about launching the GUI, but it will connect automatically if [run as a service](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1#running_as_windows_service).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Evan.